# Calling ASM Function in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, hook

I asked a question yesterday, how to call a __fastcall function, it worked great.

Now my final function i got to call is having some difficulties.

Here is the ASM function.

```
seg000:0043671F                 push    0AA2BAD1Bh
seg000:00436724                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_14]
seg000:00436727                 call    sub_458E90
```

IDA PRO labels it as.

```
int __thiscall sub_458E90(void *this, int a2)
```

It's called like this

```
sub_458E90(&v9, -1439978213);
```

Now here is the code I tried and it just gives me a Exception at runtime

```
   int addr = 0x458E90;

    __declspec(naked) void sub_458E90(int buffer, int key)
    {
        __asm{
            push key
            mov ecx, buffer
            call [addr]
             retn
        }
    }
```

Also tried

```
__declspec(naked) void sub_458E90_1(int buffer, int key)
{
    __asm{
        push key
        mov ecx, buffer
        jmp [addr]
    }
}
```

Both give me

**Application Error
The instruction at "0x00458e93" refenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be "read".**

Comment: Just guessing, but it appears you're missing your instance pointer this, on the stack.

Comment: If you mean by *this? I think thats just IDA Pro messing up why would it be a class.. if I did the previous function before it and it was same thing and it worked with just new allocated buffer pointer

Comment: What is `stepThreeAddress`?  Is that a pointer variable?

Comment: opps i'll fix that `int stepThreeAddress = 0x458E90;`

Comment: Is the data in the buffer valid? If the buffer is zeroed and is supposed to contain a pointer, the function could be dereferencing that pointer.

Comment: of course buffer is valid `char* buffer = new char[100];` `sub_458E90(buffer, 0x12345);`

Comment: @SSpoke: Not "of course"; if you don't post it, we don't know.  Don';t make people guess.

Comment: whatever solved this myself wasn't too hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved `ebx` must of been used for key. Simple as that.

`void` also must of been changed to `int` forgot about that. (most likely not to important)